# How to do broadcasting addition in Keras Functional API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following layer defined in Keras:

```py
class TextDec(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(
        self,
        n_vocab: int,
        n_ctxs: int,
        n_states: int,
        n_heads: int,
        n_layers: int,
    ):
        super(TextDec, self).__init__(name="dec")

        self.token_emb = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
            n_vocab, n_states, name="dec-token-emb"
        )

        self.position_emb = tf.Variable(
            np.zeros((n_ctxs, n_states)),
            name="dec-position-emb",
            dtype=tf.float32,
        )

        self.add = tf.keras.layers.Add(name="dec-add")

        # ...

    def call(self, inputs: List[tf.Tensor]):
        tokens, audio_features = inputs
        offset = 0

        x = self.add(
            [
                self.token_emb(tokens),
                tf.slice(self.position_emb, [offset, 0], [tokens.shape[-1], -1]),
            ]
        )

        # ...

        return x
```

When I call this with `n_ctxs = 448, n_states = 512`, it does not work. I get this:

> ValueError: Cannot merge tensors with different batch sizes. Got tensors with shapes [(5, 1, 512), (1, 512)]

I also tried using `tf.expand_dims`, but that led to a different error:

```
x = self.add([ self.token_emb(tokens),  tf.expand_dims(tf.slice(self.position_emb, [offset, 0], [tokens.shape[-1], -1]), 0) ])
```

> ValueError: Cannot merge tensors with different batch sizes. Got tensors with shapes [(5, 1, 512), (1, 1, 512)]

I also tried `tf.compat.v1.placeholder_with_default` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375665/how-to-reintroduce-none-batch-dimension-to-tensor-in-keras-tensorflow?rq=1), even though it is deprecated:

```
z = tf.slice(self.position_emb, [offset, 0], [tokens.shape[-1], -1])
z = tf.compat.v1.placeholder_with_default(z, [None, 1, 512])
x = self.add([ self.token_emb(tokens),  z ])
```

That didn't work either.

> ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 3 for '{{node PlaceholderWithDefault}} = PlaceholderWithDefaultdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,1,512]' with input shapes: [1,512].

And `tf.broadcast_to` does not work if the shape contains `None`.

However, if I change the offending line to this:

```
x = self.token_emb(tokens) + tf.slice(self.position_emb, [offset, 0], [tokens.shape[-1], -1])
```

Then it works. **Why doesn't it work when I use `Add`, and how can I get around this?**

---

The reason I want to use `Add` is because when I summarize my model, I can see the addition show up as a line like this:

```
Model: "dec"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 tokens (InputLayer)            [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 dec-token-emb (Embedding)      (None, 1, 512)       26554368    ['tokens[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 tf.__operators__.add (TFOpLamb  (None, 1, 512)      0           ['dec-token-emb[0][0]']          
 da)
```

Seeing `TFOpLambda` makes me concerned that this will prevent me from serializing my model.

Answer (score 0):

[tf.keras.layers.Add](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Add), takes as input a list of tensors, all of the same shape, and returns a single tensor (also of the same shape).

Inorder to make the above code work, you need to make sure the batch dimensions are same by using tile operation.

```
n = tf.shape(token_emb)[0]

tf.keras.layers.Add()([token_emb, tf.tile(pos_emb , (n, 1,))])
```

This is equivalent to tensor add - `token_emb + pos_emb`